# Changing XML using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML document from which I need to extract a nodeset and add a namespace. So, from a doc I extract this:

```
<List>
  <ListItem>
    <SomeData>Here is some text</SomeText>
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem>
    <SomeData>Here is some more text</SomeText>
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

and need to create this:

```
<my:List xmlsns:my='http://SomeNamespace.org>
  <my:ListItem>
    <my:SomeData>Here is some text</my:SomeText>
  </my:ListItem>
  <my:ListItem>
    <SomeData>Here is some more text</my:SomeText>
  </my:ListItem>
</my:List>
```

There will be a variable quantity of list items and the elements might change and have different name, so I need a generic solution.
Is there an easy way to do that in .Net C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XSLT for this. Check out this question: [Add a namespace to elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144713/add-a-namespace-to-elements-using-xslt)

Use the .net class XslTransform to do this in code: http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63

Comment: Thanks. Used a mixture of these links and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778299/simplest-way-to-transform-xml-to-html-with-xslt-in-c
Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx

Comment: Don't quite see this - how to add the namespace prefix to each element this way?