# Change namespace of a DOM node before/during/after import

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xhtml, namespaces

I have an XHTML document. I use XHR to import another XML document that is supposed to be XHTML, except the author forgot to put an `xmlns` on the root. As such, all nodes in the XML document have no namespace.

When I import a node from this other document and append it to my document I get a node that looks right (e.g. `<h1>Hi Mom!</h1>`) but that has no namespace. As such, the web browser applies `display:inline`.

I could fix this by using code like the following (untested)…but I'd rather not, if a better route exists:

```js
function changeNodeNamespace(node,namespace){
  var dup = document.createElementNS(namespace,node.nodeName);
  if (node.hasAttributes()){
    for (var a=node.attributes,i=a.length;i--;){
      dup.setAttributeNS(a[i].namespaceURI,a[i].nodeName,a[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (node.hasChildNodes()){
    for (var a=node.childNodes,i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
      if (a[i].nodeType==1){ // ELEMENT_NODE
        dup.appendChild(changeNodeNamespace(a[i],namespace));
      }else{
        dup.appendChild(a[i].cloneNode(false));
      }
    }
  }
  return dup;
}
```

Other than re-authoring the documents I import to have the correct namespace, **or-recursively re-creating every element/attribute/textnode in a new namespace based on the originals**, can I import the elements themselves and somehow change their namespace to `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`?

Comment: Can you change the default namespace to XHTML and use a namespace for everything else? There is also [createElementNS](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-DocCrElNS) for creating elements in a particular namespace.

Comment: @RobG The host document does have a default XHTML namespace. The loaded document does not, and that's the problem. If I edit that document to have a default XHTML namespace (thus applying the namespace to all descendants) everything works fine. The question is: _if I load an XML document that has node in the 'wrong' namespace, is there a way to transfer them without using a recursive `createElementNS` and `setAttribute` and `createTextNode` etc. to generate similar nodes in another namespace?_

Answer (score 1):

XSLT can [do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144713/add-a-namespace-to-elements-using-xslt), and a library such as [Sarissa](http://sarissa.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sarissa/sarissa/src/main/js/gr/abiss/js/sarissa/) or [AJAXSLT](http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/) can help simplify the JavaScript syntax.

Comment: What an interesting suggestion! Use XSLT to transform the element into a new one. Tricky; not quite what I was looking for, you but you certainly get a +1 for the AJAXSLT reference (real XPath in JS? Joy!).